# how to navigate to page without angular in protractor?

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

How can I go to a page that does not contain angular with protractor? My test looks like this:

```
browser.driver.get('https://www.mysitewithlogin.com');
```

The result is:

```
Message:Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "angular could not be found on the window"
```

So the site starts with a login page and does not contain angular. Is it uberhaupt possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use below line of code before launching application.

`browser.ignoreSynchronization=true;`

By writing above line, it wont wait for angular. It considers the app as normal app.

Answer (score -1):

you can move back a page by using this line `"browser.navigate().back();"`